# Бан аккаунта разработчика Google Play

Tags: google-play-console

Начнем с того, что все было хорошо: выполнял задание на фрилансе. Делал конвертацию сайта в приложение. Сделал, далее создал аккаунт разработчика Google и затем выложил приложение. Казалось бы, что приложение прошло публикацию и даже какое-то время спустя был доступ к Google Play Console, однако спустя ровно 1 день мне прилетело вот такое сообщение на почту:

> This is a notification that your Google Play Publisher account has been terminated.
>
> REASON FOR TERMINATION: Prior violations of the Developer Program Policies and Developer Distribution Agreement by this or associated accounts as outlined in previous emails sent to the registered email address(es) of the Publisher account(s).
>
> Google Play Publisher suspensions are associated with developers, and may span multiple account registrations and related Google services.
>
> You can visit the Developer Policy Center to better understand how we enforce Developer Program Policies. If you’ve reviewed the policy and feel this termination may have been in error, please reach out to our policy support team.
>
> Do not attempt to register a new developer account. We will not be restoring your account at this time.
>
> The Google Play Team

Где и в каком месте были нарушены соглашения тот еще вопрос. Кто знает, как вернуть аккаунт?

Comment: насколько, например, я знаю - уже никак. Почитайте такое: https://habr.com/post/231009/ и погуглите "Гугл банит разработчиков". Попробуйте написать претензию в поддержку, может вам повезет)

Comment: Да, прогноз отрицательный. Вы можете 2 вещи сделать - написать в техподдержку и скрестить пальцы - вдруг вам не робот ответит и будет объяснение и восстановление. Это маловероятно. 2 вариант - поднять шумиху на западных площадках - там могут увидеть живые люди из гугла и может быть акк разблокируют. Этот вариант, понятно, сложнее. Вот статья на тему свежая: https://habr.com/company/jugru/blog/433768/

Comment: Спасибо за советы. Остается только надеяться на лучшее.

Comment: Достучаться до них нереально. К сожалению, можете забыть про этот аккаунт :(

Comment: Привет. Вам удалось понять как гугл понял что вы ранее чем уже регистрировались как разработчик?